# how to show the output after the form submit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How to edit the code so that the `function calculateTotal` can run when the submit button is pressed, and the output is how after the submit button press but not directly show to people by keep adding.

```js
var person = [];
person["person1"]=1; 
person["person2"]=2;
person["person3"]=3;
person["person4"]=4;
person["person5"]=5;

var elec = [];
elec["elecuse"] = 0;
elec["elec1"] = 100*(5455/12);
elec["elec2"] = 150*(5455/12);
elec["elec3"] = 200*(5455/12);
elec["elec4"] = 250*(5455/12);
elec["elec5"] = 300*(5455/12);
elec["elec6"] = 350*(5455/12);
elec["elec7"] = 400*(5455/12);
elec["elec8"] = 450*(5455/12);
elec["elec9"] = 500*(5455/12);
elec["elec10"] = 550*(5455/12);
elec["elec11"] = 600*(5455/12);
elec["elec12"] = 650*(5455/12);
elec["elec13"] = 700*(5455/12);

function getNumberperson()
{  
    var numberperson=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var selectedPerson = theForm.elements["selectedperson"];
    for(var i = 0; i < selectedPerson.length; i++)
    {
        if(selectedPerson[i].checked)
        {
            numberperson = person[selectedPerson[i].value];
        }
    }
    return numberperson;
}

function getElectotal()
{
    var electotal=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var selectedElec = theForm.elements["electricity"];     
    electotal = elec[selectedElec.value];
    return electotal;
}

function waste()
{
    var mustwaste=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var waste = theForm.elements["waste"];

    if(waste.checked==true)
    {
        mustwaste=(692/12);
    }
    return mustwaste;
}

function recyclealu()
{
    var recyclealu=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var yesalu = theForm.elements["yesalu"];

    if(yesalu.checked==true)
    {
        recyclealu=-89.38;
    }
    return recyclealu;
}

function recycleplas()
{
    var recycleplas=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
    var yesplas = theForm.elements["yesplas"];

    if(yesplas.checked==true)
    {
        recycleplas=-35.56;
    }
    return recycleplas;
}

function checkAllRecycles() {
    const recycleBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.recycle');

  if (recycleBoxes) {
    recycleBoxes.forEach((recycleBox) => {
      if (!recycleBox.checked) {
        recycleBox.checked = 'checked';
      }
    })
  }
  calculateTotal();
}

function calculateTotal()
{
    var totalco =  getNumberperson()*getElectotal() + waste() + recyclealu() + recycleplas();
    
    //display the result

    document.getElementById('totalConsumption').innerHTML = +totalco.toFixed(2);

}

//add a function to hide the result on page loading at the start
function hideTotal()
{
    document.getElementById('totalConsumption').innerHTML = "0";
} 

function vwaste()
{
    var cw = document.getElementsByName('waste');
    for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++)
    {
       if (cw[i].type == 'checkbox')
        {
        if (cw[i].checked) {return true}
        }
    }
  return false;
}

function allvalidate()
{
    var error = document.getElementById("error")
    if (!vwaste())
        {
            // Changing content and color of content
            error.textContent = "Waste must be select"
            error.style.color = "red"
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    
    
}
```

```html
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
    <div id="all">
        <form action="/action_page.php" id="energyform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div>
            <div class="cont_order">
               <fieldset>
                <legend>Carbon Footprint Calculator</legend>
                <label >Number of Person Live in Household</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person1" onclick="calculateTotal()" />1&nbsp</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />2&nbsp</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />3&nbsp</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person4" onclick="calculateTotal()" />4&nbsp</label>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person5" onclick="calculateTotal()" />5&nbsp</label>
<br/>
                <label><i class="fa fa-flash"></i>Waste</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="waste" name='waste' onclick="calculateTotal()" /><span id="error"></span>

                <hr><label><i class="fa fa-flash"></i>Energy Consumption Per Month</label></hr>
<br/>
                <label>&nbspElectricity&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
                <select id="electricity" name='electricity' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                <option value="elecuse">0kWh</option>
                <option value="elec1">100kWh</option>
                <option value="elec2">150kWh</option>
                <option value="elec3">200kWh</option>
                <option value="elec4">250kWh</option>
                <option value="elec5">300kWh</option>
                <option value="elec6">350kWh (Avg US)</option>
                <option value="elec7">400kWh (Avg MY)</option>
                <option value="elec8">450kWh</option>
                <option value="elec9">500kWh (Avg AS)</option>
                <option value="elec10">550kWh</option>
                <option value="elec11">600kWh</option>
                <option value="elec12">650kWh</option>
                <option value="elec13">700kWh</option>
                </select>

                <hr><label><i class="fa fa-flash"></i>Recycle </label></hr>
<br/>
                <label for='yesalu' class="alu">&nbspAluminium and Steel&nbsp&nbsp</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="yesalu" name='yesalu' class="recycle" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
<br/>
                <label for='yesplas' class="plas">&nbspPlastic&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="yesplas" name='yesplas' class="recycle" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
<br/>
                <button type="button" onclick="checkAllRecycles()">Select All</button> 
<br/>
                <p>Total CO2 produced per year per household:</p>
                <div id="totalConsumption">0</div>
                <label>pounds</label>
                <div>US Household average is 21,820 lbs per year.</div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="allvalidate()" />
            <input type='reset' id='reset' value='Reset' onclick="hideTotal()" />
        </div>  
       </form>
                    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Why don't use `addEventListener("submit")` method on **form**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the call to `calculateTotal()` to the form's `onsubmit` instead of doing it in all the `onclick`.

Also take calls to it out of other functions.

```js
var person = [];
person["person1"] = 1;
person["person2"] = 2;
person["person3"] = 3;
person["person4"] = 4;
person["person5"] = 5;

var elec = [];
elec["elecuse"] = 0;
elec["elec1"] = 100 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec2"] = 150 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec3"] = 200 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec4"] = 250 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec5"] = 300 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec6"] = 350 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec7"] = 400 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec8"] = 450 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec9"] = 500 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec10"] = 550 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec11"] = 600 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec12"] = 650 * (5455 / 12);
elec["elec13"] = 700 * (5455 / 12);

function getNumberperson() {
  var numberperson = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
  var selectedPerson = theForm.elements["selectedperson"];
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedPerson.length; i++) {
    if (selectedPerson[i].checked) {
      numberperson = person[selectedPerson[i].value];
    }
  }
  return numberperson;
}

function getElectotal() {
  var electotal = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
  var selectedElec = theForm.elements["electricity"];
  electotal = elec[selectedElec.value];
  return electotal;
}

function waste() {
  var mustwaste = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
  var waste = theForm.elements["waste"];

  if (waste.checked == true) {
    mustwaste = (692 / 12);
  }
  return mustwaste;
}

function recyclealu() {
  var recyclealu = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
  var yesalu = theForm.elements["yesalu"];

  if (yesalu.checked == true) {
    recyclealu = -89.38;
  }
  return recyclealu;
}

function recycleplas() {
  var recycleplas = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["energyform"];
  var yesplas = theForm.elements["yesplas"];

  if (yesplas.checked == true) {
    recycleplas = -35.56;
  }
  return recycleplas;
}

function checkAllRecycles() {
  const recycleBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.recycle');

  if (recycleBoxes) {
    recycleBoxes.forEach((recycleBox) => {
      if (!recycleBox.checked) {
        recycleBox.checked = 'checked';
      }
    })
  }
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var totalco = getNumberperson() * getElectotal() + waste() + recyclealu() + recycleplas();

  //display the result

  document.getElementById('totalConsumption').innerHTML = +totalco.toFixed(2);

}

//add a function to hide the result on page loading at the start
function hideTotal() {
  document.getElementById('totalConsumption').innerHTML = "0";
}

function vwaste() {
  var cw = document.getElementsByName('waste');
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    if (cw[i].type == 'checkbox') {
      if (cw[i].checked) {
        return true
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function allvalidate() {
  var error = document.getElementById("error")
  if (!vwaste()) {
    // Changing content and color of content
    error.textContent = "Waste must be select"
    error.style.color = "red"
    return false;
  }
  return true;


}
```

```html
<body onload='hideTotal()'>
  <div id="all">
    <form action="/action_page.php" id="energyform" onsubmit="calculateTotal();return false;">
      <div>
        <div class="cont_order">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Carbon Footprint Calculator</legend>
            <label>Number of Person Live in Household</label><br/>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person1"/>1&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person2"  />2&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person3"  />3&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person4" />4&nbsp</label>
            <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="selectedperson" value="person5"  />5&nbsp</label>
            <br/>
            <label><i class="fa fa-flash"></i>Waste</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="waste" name='waste'  /><span id="error"></span>

            <hr><label><i class="fa fa-flash"></i>Energy Consumption Per Month</label></hr>
            <br/>
            <label>&nbspElectricity&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
            <select id="electricity" name='electricity' >
              <option value="elecuse">0kWh</option>
              <option value="elec1">100kWh</option>
              <option value="elec2">150kWh</option>
              <option value="elec3">200kWh</option>
              <option value="elec4">250kWh</option>
              <option value="elec5">300kWh</option>
              <option value="elec6">350kWh (Avg US)</option>
              <option value="elec7">400kWh (Avg MY)</option>
              <option value="elec8">450kWh</option>
              <option value="elec9">500kWh (Avg AS)</option>
              <option value="elec10">550kWh</option>
              <option value="elec11">600kWh</option>
              <option value="elec12">650kWh</option>
              <option value="elec13">700kWh</option>
            </select>

            <hr><label><i class="fa fa-flash"></i>Recycle </label></hr>
            <br/>
            <label for='yesalu' class="alu">&nbspAluminium and Steel&nbsp&nbsp</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="yesalu" name='yesalu' class="recycle"  />
            <br/>
            <label for='yesplas' class="plas">&nbspPlastic&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="yesplas" name='yesplas' class="recycle" />
            <br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="checkAllRecycles()">Select All</button>
            <br/>
            <p>Total CO2 produced per year per household:</p>
            <div id="totalConsumption">0</div>
            <label>pounds</label>
            <div>US Household average is 21,820 lbs per year.</div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="allvalidate()" />
        <input type='reset' id='reset' value='Reset' onclick="hideTotal()" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: it work! but when the select all button is click, the output run out again

Comment: That's because `checkAllRecycles` calls `calculateTotal`.